# CollectionView crashing in NSISEngine after a few scrolls

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view that has a horizontal flow layout. After scrolling through about 4 to 5 cells, the code crashes with a SIGABRT error message that I can't find anywhere else online.

Assertion failure in void _removeFromEngineVarTable(NSISEngineVar)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1562/Foundation/Layout.subproj/IncrementalSimplex/NSISEngine.m:1518

Here is the code for the cellForItem:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "listingCell", for: indexPath) as? ListingCollectionViewCell {
        cell.listing = listings[indexPath.item]

        cell.segmentedControl.removeAllSegments()
        cell.listing.termContracts.forEach {
            var title = ""

            switch $0.availableFor {
            case "Fall":                title = "Fa"
            case "Fall/Winter":         title = "Fw"
            case "Winter":              title = "Wi"
            case "Spring":              title = "Sp"
            case "Spring/Summer":       title = "Ss"
            case "Summer":              title = "Su"
            case "Year Round":          title = "Year"
            default:                    title = ""
            }

            cell.segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: title, at: cell.segmentedControl.numberOfSegments, animated: false)
        }

        cell.contactLabel.text = cell.listing.contactPhone
        cell.contactPersonLabel.text = cell.listing.contactPerson
        cell.addressLabel.text = cell.listing.address

        //Default data to first contract
        if cell.listing.termContracts.isEmpty {
            cell.rentLabel.text = "N/A"
            cell.sharedPrivateLabel.text = ""
        } else {
            if let rent = cell.listing.termContracts[0].rent {
                cell.rentLabel.text = rent == 0 ? "Free" : "$\(rent)/mo"
            }
            if let sharedPrivate = cell.listing.termContracts[0].sharedPrivate {
                cell.sharedPrivateLabel.text = sharedPrivate
            }
        }

        cell.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
if let rent = cell.listing.termContracts[0].rent {
    cell.rentLabel.text = rent == 0 ? "Free" : "$\(rent)/mo"
}
```

When I replace this with

```
if let rent = cell.listing.termContracts[0].rent {
    cell.rentLabel.text = rent == 0 ? "Free" : "$\(cell.listing.termContracts[0].rent)"
}
```

It works perfectly fine. But because rent is optional, I get the ugly "Optional(___)" when it renders out. Is this a bug?? I don't see any reason for anything to break, because I'm handling everything safely. I also don't see any fundamental differences between if letting rent and just throwing it in there.

The collection view also crashes when I make it scroll to a specific index, which makes me think that it's a reusable issue?

EDIT: IB details

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK but try this: `cell.rentLabel.text = rent == 0 ? "Free" : "$\(cell.listing.termContracts[0].rent!)"`. That gets rid of the "Optional" in the text, but now do you start crashing again?

Comment: Yeah. Still crashing

Comment: I thought so. So the optionality is a red herring; it's the _particular text_ you are trying to insert into the label. You could probably get this crash with text `"x"`.

Comment: I've added more details above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an autolayout issue. NSISEngine is the autolayout "solver". You have not described your interface so it's impossible to help more precisely, but there must be something difficult or time-consuming to solve in your autolayout constraints (inequalities perhaps? lowered priorities?), and it is probably the constraints on `rentLabel` or something connected to it (or the layout-determining properties of `rentLabel`).

Start by simplifying the layout of this label, even this gives the "wrong" interface, and see if you can make the problem go away. If you can, try to restore your constraints in a more efficient way.

Comment: Interesting. But why does it render properly for optional variables? Does autolayout handle that correctly? Currently the text is just cut off with ".." so there are no resizing issues. If anything, the unwrapped variable is always shorter than the "optional(___)" version

Comment: Well that might be the reason, since then with shorter text we have to contract the label's width (I presume). I really can't be specific as you have revealed none of the relevant details, but now you know where to look. There's a good WWDC 2018 video on autolayout efficiencies. This is going to be really interesting when you finally track it down!

Comment: I've added more to the post!

Answer (score 1):

I added a fixed width constraint to the uiLabel, and it stopped crashing. Thanks to @Matt the Legend for helping me figure this one out!

Comment: I'm going to edit your title to include NSISEngine to make this more useful to future generations. :)

Comment: I still think, however, that your teardown and rebuild of the segmented control is problematic.

Comment: Can I chat with you elsewhere to discuss it?